# Integration $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem :

Integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}$

I tried : Let $x^2-4 =t^2 \Rightarrow 2xdx = 2tdt$

$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4} \Rightarrow \frac{t^3 dt}{\sqrt{t^2+4}(t^4-8t+16)}$

But I think this made the integral too complicated... please suggest how to proceed.. Thanks..

Comment: You can try an [Euler Substition](http://www2.onu.edu/~m-caragiu.1/bonus_files/EULER-SU.pdf), but that would be overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Besides to @Ron's answer, you can see that the form [Differential binomial](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial) is ruling the integral here. Let to write integrand as follows:

$$\int(x^2-4)^{1/2}x^{-4}~dx$$

So, $m=-4,~~p=1/2,~~n=2$ and so $\frac{m+1}{n}+p=-1\in\mathbb Z$ and so the method says that you can use the following nice substitution:
$$x^2-4=t^{2}x^4$$

Answer (score 2):

Use a hyperbolic cosine substitution: $x=2 \cosh{t}$; $dx = 2 \sinh{t}\, dt$.  Then the integral is equal to

$$\frac14 \int dt \frac{\sinh^2{t}}{\cosh^4{t}} = \frac14 \int dt \, \left (\text{sech}^2{t} -  \text{sech}^4{t}\right ) $$

This integral is easy once you recognize that $d(\tanh{t}) = \text{sech}^2{t}$ and $1-\text{sech}^2{t}=\tanh^2{t}$:

$$\frac14 \int dt \, \left (\text{sech}^2{t} -  \text{sech}^4{t}\right ) = \frac14 \int d(\tanh{t}) \tanh^2{t} = \frac{1}{12} \tanh^3{t}+C  $$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  Then just substitute back to get the integral in $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}}{x^3}dx$

Put $\frac1x=z\implies \frac{-1}{x^2}dx=dz$

So it boils to, $-\displaystyle\int z\sqrt{1-4z^2}dz$

Again put $1-4z^2=t\implies -8zdz=dt$

Hence we get, $\frac18\displaystyle\int \sqrt{t}dt=\frac{1}{12}t^{3/2}+C=\frac{1}{12}(1-4z^2)^{3/2}+C=\frac{(1-4x^2)^{3/2}}{12x^3}+C$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As the radical contains $x^2-4,$

put $x=2\sec\theta$

$$\implies \int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}dx=\int \frac{2|\tan\theta|}{\sec^4\theta} 2\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta=4\cdot \text{sign}(\tan\theta)\int \sin^2\theta \cos \theta d\theta$$

Putting $\sin\theta=u,$

$$4\text{sign}(\tan\theta)\int \sin^2\theta \cos \theta d\theta$$
$$=4\text{sign}(\tan\theta)\int u^2 du=\frac43\cdot\text{sign}(\tan\theta)\cdot u^3+K$$
$$=\frac43\cdot\text{sign}(\tan\theta)\cdot \sin^3\theta+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary  constant of indefinite integral

Now, $\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\pm\sqrt{1-\left(\frac2x\right)^2}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}x$

Now observe that the sign$(\sin\theta)=$ sign$(\tan\theta)\cdot$sign$\left(\frac2x\right)$

Comment: So we can straight away put $u=\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}x$